# VBA Calling subroutine using If-Then - Goto

Tags: vba, excel, calling-convention

```
    Sub Testcopy()

    X = MsgBox("Press 1 to clear sheet or press 2 to copy")

        If X = 1 Then GoTo clearsheet
        If X = 2 Then GoTo Copysheet

        'MsgBox ("Incorrect entry")
    End Sub

    Sub clearsheet()

    sheetclearname = InputBox(" Enter the sheet you want to clear")
    Worksheets(sheetclearname).Select
    Worksheets(sheetclearname).UsedRange.Clear
    End Sub


    Sub Copysheet()
    Worksheets("Inputs").Activate
    Worksheets("Inputs").Range("Expenses").Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```

Guys

I am trying to make a main routine which ask the user to enter option 1 or 2
Option 1 takes to subroutine clearsheet and it clears the sheet chosen

option 2 activates sub routine CopySheet and this copies from tab input range expenses to sheet 3

when I run the macro I get label not defined

1. What is label not defined here and how to make this works

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Testcopy()

X = MsgBox("Press 1 to clear sheet or press 2 to copy")

    If X = 1 Then Call clearsheet
    If X = 2 Then Call Copysheet

    'MsgBox ("Incorrect entry")
End Sub
```

Comment: To add to Gary's answer, `GoTo` requires a label to jump to. A label is an identifier, starting in the first column of text, in the _current_ procedure (`Sub` or `Function`), followed by a colon `:`, for example: `Here:`, or `There:`, or `Error_Handler:`. Generally they are a _Bad Idea™_ as they can lead to difficult to debug code. What you've done is write a couple of subroutines (which is _excellent_ and the preferred way of doing things!), but failed to call them correctly. Gary's answer will do what you want. (Though `Call` isn't required in most situations.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub expensecopy()

    X = InputBox("Press 1 to clear sheet or press 2 to copy")

        If X = 1 Then Call clearsheet
        If X = 2 Then Call copysheet
        If X <> 1 Or 2 Then Call usererrorhandler
   End Sub



Sub usererrorhandler()

    Z = MsgBox("Incorrect entry, Please enter 1 or 2")
    End Sub

Sub clearsheet()

    sheetclearname = InputBox(" Enter the sheet you want to clear")
    Worksheets(sheetclearname).Select
    Worksheets(sheetclearname).UsedRange.Clear
    End Sub


Sub copysheet()
    Worksheets("Inputs").Activate
    Worksheets("Inputs").Range("Expenses").Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

     End Sub
```

Thanks guys , here is the updated code, it works perfect. Just curious as an add-on question.

I want to send the user if he enter anything other than 1 or 2 , from the routine usererrorhandler back to the option to enter the option 1 or 2 rather than rerun the macro.

Any suggestions ?